# facilitatorAccessToken to verify transaction details (PERMISSION_DENIED)

Tags: curl, paypal

Brand new to PayPal, tinkering with sandbox. My *test* orders are going through OK.

I would like to verify orders from my server and handle the provisioning tasks in the background for successful orders.

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
// data has things that are of interest, see below.
....
}
```

`data` has :

```
{
  "orderID": "4P1187891ORDERID",
  "payerID": "4MEHE6UPAYERID",
  "paymentID": null,
  "billingToken": null,
  "facilitatorAccessToken": "aHR0cHM6Ly9hcGkuc2FFACILITATORACCESSTOKENtL3YyL2NoZWNrb3V0L29yZGVycy80UDExODc4"
}
```

Their [doc says](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/get-transaction/) this is how i can get the transaction details:

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5O190127TN364715T \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

So I carve my curl command as:

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/4P1187891ORDERID \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer aHR0cHM6Ly9hcGkuc2FFACILITATORACCESSTOKENtL3YyL2NoZWNrb3V0L29yZGVycy80UDExODc4"
```

I use the `facilitatorAccessToken` as the **Access-Token** in curl above, and it is failing as:

```
{"name":"NOT_AUTHORIZED","details":[{"issue":"PERMISSION_DENIED","description":"You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource."}],"message":"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.","debug_id":"420XXXXX03","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PERMISSION_DENIED","rel":"information_link"}]}
```

Has anyone suffered this before? I am assuming `facilitatorAccessToken` can be used as `Access-Token` to get Transaction Details - is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone suffered this before? I am assuming facilitatorAccessToken can be used as Access-Token to get Transaction Details - is this not the case?

That's not the case. See "a curl command" on this page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token

Since you have a server doing processing with the data, you ought to be using a server-based integration for order creation and capture.  You'll need two routes, one for 'Create Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/). Once you have those two routes, pair them with this approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server